# Package for Insert/Update old salary value in emp_sal_history table whenever salary get changed without trigger

Tags: oracle, function, package, procedure

This is my Function

```
create or replace
function sal_incr
(
p_grade number)
return number
is
v_inc number;
begin
select raise_percent into v_inc from sal_inc where grade_id = p_grade;
return  1 + (v_inc/100);
end;
```

This is my procedure:

```
create or replace 
procedure sal_increm 
is
begin
UPDATE emp_task SET sal = sal * sal_incr(grade_id);
end;
```

how to do that package.. without using triggers how to update "old sal","modified by" and "modified on" in separate table

Comment: does this work UPDATE emp_task SET sal = sal * sal_incr(grade_id), modified_by = USER,modified_on = sysdate where emp = emp_id:  ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have multiple DML statements in a procedure; they'd be rather less useful if you couldn't. You can do a single insert into your history table based on the data in the task table, adding the executing user with [the `USER` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions227.htm) and and the current time with [`SYSDATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions191.htm).

```
create or replace 
procedure sal_increm 
is
begin
  insert into emp_sal_history (empno, old_sal, modified_by, modified_on)
  select empno, sal, user, sysdate
  from emp_task;

  update emp_task set sal = sal * sal_incr(grade_id);
end;
/
```

If you want to record the new salary as well you can calculate that in the insert too.

This will record a history record even for employees whose grade doesn't get an increment. If you have those or want to handle that possibility and exclude them, you can add

```
where sal_incr(grade_id) != 1
```

You could add that to the update as well.